# How to get the coordinates that spits out min/max value from the function in R?

Tags: r, optimization

How do I get the coordinates that spits out min/max value from the function?

my function code is :

```
myfunct <- function(theta){
for (h in 1:nrow(temp)){
theta_i <- theta[temp[h,1]]              #i-th position
theta_j <- theta[temp[h,2]]              #j-th position
L1 <- -y[temp[h,2],temp[h,1]] * (theta_i - theta_j) + log(1+exp(theta_i - 
theta_j))
}
L2 <- L1 + 0.5 * lambda * norm(theta, "2")^2
return(L2)
}
```

my coordinates are:

```
e1 <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
e2 <- c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
e3 <- c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
e4 <- c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
e5 <- c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)
e6 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
e7 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)
e8 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)
e9 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)
e10 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
unitvect <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)

points <- list(e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9,e10,unitvect)
```

I tried with "which" function something like:

```
for (i in 1:10){
 min <- which(points[[i]] == min(myfunct(points[[i]])
}
```

but I do not know the syntax on using which function, and I want to store coordinate that gives min value from the function in to variable called "min". 
 Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Apply function to all points: `result = sapply(points, myfunct)`. Then `min_point = points[[which.min(result)]]`.

Comment: @Gregor thanks, but could you please tell me why you put double square brackets instead of one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-and-notations-for-accessing-the-elements-of-a-lis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment to answer so this can be resolved.

Use `sapply` to apply your function to each item of your list:

```
result = sapply(points, myfunct)
```

Then use `which.min` and `which.max` to get the index of the min and max results. Example:

```
min_point = points[[which.min(result)]]
```